# How can I see if a request passed well in a .jsp file?

Tags: sql, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have a .jsp file in whom I make a sql request.

I haven't choice to do tha because I'm on a web app who is completely develop like that.

And I want to see if my sql request is fine (like with a var_dump() using php), how can I make this ?

My code :

```
<c:set var="sql_select" value="COMMUNE.INSEE_COMMUNE, COMMUNE.NOM_COMMUNE_MIN, COMMUNAUTE_COMMUNE.NOM_CC"/>
<c:set var="sql_from" value="CG.COMMUNE, CG.COMMUNAUTE_COMMUNE"/>
<c:set var="sql_where" value="COMMUNE.ID_CC=COMMUNAUTE_COMMUNE.ID_CC AND COMMUNE.INSEE_COMMUNE = ${param.insee}"/>

<sql:query var="recordset">
    SELECT ${sql_select} FROM ${sql_from} WHERE ${sql_where}
</sql:query>
```

I just want to know the value of "recordset".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its better to do your SQL in servlets.

Comment: Yep I know, but there isn't any servelts in this project :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JSTL `forEach` construct to loop over the `recordset` now.

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${recordset.rows}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${row.INSEE_COMMUNE}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.NOM_COMMUNE_MIN}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.NOM_CC}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Ideally, your data retrieval code should be in the *persistence* layer, the results of which are then passed to your JSP by a controller servlet. The JSP would then simply loop over the results to display the data.

Comment: Thanks Ravi Thapliyal :D